# Overriding Meteor's oauth package

Tags: javascript, oauth, meteor

I need to override a function which is placed in oauth_server.js in Meteor's oauth package.

I want to replace -

```
var closePopup = function(res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  var content =
        '<html><head><script>window.close()</script></head></html>';
  res.end(content, 'utf-8');
};
```

with something like -

```
var closePopup = function(res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  var content =
        '<html><head><script>window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/";</script></head></html>';
  res.end(content, 'utf-8');
};
```

The package is a core meteor package so i don't think i can just remove it and add a modified version.

I tried to add the edited variable (function) to my main server code but have seen no changes to meteor's behavior.

Much thanks in advance, Daniel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a package to override the existing one.

If you want to replace `oauth`'s files you should make a new package containing all the files from the package from oauth.

Then place this new package in `/packages` and run `meteor add oauth` to add it into your project. The new package will override the existing standard meteor one.

You need to consider this option though, it means that you have to keep it up to date every time meteor updates its packages.

Comment: I want to override the oauth package.
When i create a modified package and try "meteor add oauth" i get "oauth: no such package"

Comment: Did you add this package into the `/packages` folder? and its called oauth? Earlier I didn't know which specific oauth package you wanted to replace? is the plain 'oauth' the one?

Comment: Btw if you want to use Emily's answer from yesterday you needed to run `meteor remove oauth` and add in your package, but that step is slightly different. Keep in mind you need to remove `standard-app-packages` and add in all the ones you want manually, without `oauth`, but instead using your custom package

Comment: Where can i get a list of all standard-app-packages?

Comment: And yes, it's the plain 'oauth'.

Comment: When i tried adding oauth after changing some stuff, it gives me a "The package named webapp does not exist." error.

Comment: While trying to deploy.

Comment: Hmm not sure about that one, did you `meteor add webapp` it in? Its supposed to be in the standard-app-packages (which you can get a list of here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/standard-app-packages/package.js

Comment: & you're right btw the dependencies make this a bit tricky because oauth is part of some other package, i thought you mentioned it but you might have to alter that package too to use your new oauth package instead of the standard one, did overriding it on its own not work?

Comment: No, it doesn't really work.
Adding standard-app-packages on the client side gives me a 'TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'imply'.

Comment: Is your project a Meteor 0.6.5 project? imply was just added in very recently. What about the plain override method is that not doing anything? The standard-apps package doesn't have the oauth stuff it comes from whichever package one you want to use (facebook-oauth?) as a dependency

Comment: It probably is just a version thing.

Comment: After matching the right versions of meteor and the package, everything went smooth. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to override the function I recently needed to override `OAuth._checkRedirectUrlOrigin` with my own. Because the function says it meant to be overridden if needed in meteor source code I did it this way:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  Package['oauth'].OAuth._checkRedirectUrlOrigin = function (redirectUrl) {
    console.log(redirectUrl);
    var appHost = "http://localhost:3000";
    var appHostReplacedLocalhost = Meteor.absoluteUrl(undefined, {
      replaceLocalhost: true
    });
    return (
      redirectUrl.substr(0, appHost.length) !== appHost &&
      redirectUrl.substr(0, appHostReplacedLocalhost.length) !== appHostReplacedLocalhost
    );
  };
  // testing if it worked :)
  Meteor.setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(Package['oauth'].Oauth._checkRedirectUrlOrigin.toString());
  }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Wow. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I just couldn't figure out how to do the actual overriding of a meteor package method.